# Possible to always hide a subset of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a shop set up with lots of tables that are joined together in various ways, as per usual.

In my products table, I have a field called 'status'. If the status = 4, then the product is archived.

I want to ensure that no queries ever return anything with a status of 4. Right now I'm about to add a `AND status <> 4` to every SQL query I can find.

Is there a better way to do this, or is that the only way?

Comment: That is pretty much the only way, yes.. Except if you make a table that holds the archived products. Then you just move them from the main table to the archive table.

Comment: How many products do you have?  Luc has the correct answer.  But if you have lots and lots of products, you might want to move them to a different table for performance reasons.

Comment: Luc has indeed a great point. I totally forgot about views.. That might be a good option here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a view that doesn't show status = 4 and use that view in your query's instead.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably changing a product's status between archived and unarchived is a pretty rare operation, while selecting from your product table is extremely common.  Therefore you should make a table `archived` and move all archived products there.

This would be the best-performing solution.

If you also occasionally wanted to view all products, whether archived or not, then you could also make a view that combines the `archived` and `products` tables.